# Is there something wrong with this problem statement? [Analysis Preliminaries]

Tags: real-analysis

The problem seems to be asking the pre-image of $f(B)=[-1,1]$ where $f(x)=x^2$. The solutions manual provided that the pre=image is $f^{-1}(B)=[-1,1]$ which does not seem right to me.
[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: because there's no real number squared is negative.

Comment: B being the image $[-1,1]$ with $f(x)=x^2$. If $f^{-1}(B)=[-1,1]$, how can I find a real number $x\in [-1,1]$ such that $f(x)=-1$?

Comment: You can't, but the point is that *you don't need to*.

Comment: You can't, but that's irrelevant. Review the definition of $f^{-1}([-1,1]).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-image is $[-1, 1]$. The numbers from that set, squared, will be in $B$, and any number outside of that set, squared, will fall outside $B$.

I am not sure what is confusing you. Perhaps the fact that not every element of $B$ will be an image of something in $[-1,1]$? That is true but not relevant for deciding what the pre-image is. Incidentally, what is true is that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$ where the inclusion is *strict* in our case (the LHS is $[0,1]$).

Comment: that was really embarassing! I guess I took too long of a break from this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = [-1,1]$, and let $f(x) = x^2$.

Claim $f^{-1}(B) = [-1,1]$.

Proof:

First suppose $x \in [-1,1]$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;&x \in [-1,1]\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|x| \le 1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&0 \le x^2 \le 1&&\text{[since $x^2 \ge 0$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-1 \le x^2 \le 1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 \in [-1,1]\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x) \in B\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \in f^{-1}(B)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that $[-1,1] \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$.

Next, suppose $x \in f^{-1}(B)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;&x \in f^{-1}(B)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x) \in B\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 \in [-1,1]\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 \in [0,1]&&\text{[since $x^2 \ge 0$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&0 \le x^2  \le 1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|x| \le 1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-1 \le x \le 1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \in [-1,1]\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq [-1,1]$.

Thus, we have both inclusions, hence $f^{-1}(B)=[-1,1]$.